# Rebinding "switch to next window" keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard

It [seems](http://macmost.com/downloads/MacMostKeyboardShortcutsLion.pdf) that the default shortcut for switching to the next window in Lion is <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>.

Is there any way I can rebind this to something else? (Preferably using built-in software.) I tried looking for it in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it. It's under:

1. **System Preferences > Keyboard**
2. Click on the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab
3. **Keyboard & Text Input > Move Focus to next Window**